# Connecting a windows phone 8 application to remote mysql database

Tags: c#, mysql, json, linq

Please explain to me like a two year old on how to connect to a remote MySQL database, pass queries and receive data. I am using a Linux server if that information is needed. I have had people talking about JSON, Serializing and Deserializing JSON or using LINQ to JSON but honestly, this is Greek to me. Any sample codes and references will be appreciated.

Comment: There are at least 5 questions here: 1. How to connect to the MySQL database 2. How to pass queries to MySQL 3. How to receive data from MySQL 4. How to use JSON with MySQL 5. Should I use JSON serialize-deserialize or JSON LINQ(off-topic, but nonetheless). Perhaps it is better to begin with such small concrete more or less answerable questions rather than with gigantic global all-incorporating issues. And most of those small questions are already answered either here or on other resources.

Answer (score 3):

The Phone cannot talk directly to the MySQL server, so you need to break this down into simpler problems to solve - you'll need *something* on a webserver (an API) that can talk to your MySQL server, and convert it to a format to send "over the air". You'll then need something on the phone to turn that back into *something useful* and do something with it (and potentially cache it on the client).

This is where you veer into the realms of opinions and your actual budget, requirements, etc. but you *could* build a RESTful API, secured with OAuth, that uses JSON over HTTP for delivering to the phone. Similarly, you *could* build a SOAP webservice, and just add it as a Service Reference. Or even build it on top of Azure.

Comment: Something is still not clear, can php be put somewhere? How many intermediaries are there between the wp8 and the server>

Comment: So you *could* use PHP on the webserver, to act as the intermediary between the client and the database server

Answer (score 0):

I believe you cannot directly access MySQL database form WP8 (I think so, they might have added support though). Therefore, if I were you I would use a web service for that purpose. How you can do that (You wanted me to explain like I'm teaching a 2 years old):

1- Open Visual Studio

2- Click New Project

3- Go to C#

4- Navigate to WCF

5- Create a WCF Application

After the VS created default template, go to MySQL website, and download their official driver, reference it.

To make a web service (the default template creates an interface for you named IService1), go to that interface and add this method:

```
[OperationContract]
public Boolean Manipulate(String Text);
```

Go back to the Service1 and implement the method:

```
public Boolean Manipulate(String Text) {
    try {
        MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection ("Connection String");
        MySqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand(); 
        con.Open();
        cmd.CommandText = Text;
        int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
        return i > 0;
    }
    Catch(Exception ex) {
        return false;
    }
 }
```

To access the web service from WP8, create a WP8 app in VS. Right click the project, go to add and click service reference. Copy past the WCF url that the VS gives you after running it in the address bar and click go. Now click the Advanced button and check mark "Always generate message contract" while unchecking the "Reused type in reference assembly".

Now go to the class where you wana consume the service and add a method like this.

```
public async Task Manipulate () {
     ServiceReference1.Service1Client Client = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client();
     var i = await Client.ManipulateAsync(new ServiceReference1.ManipulateRequest("SQL Command"));
     // to get the result use i.Result;
}
```

For readin the data you have two options, make a method of return type "String", when you make your query, Serialize it using the XmlSerializer class or create a model and set the return type of the model the same as the model type, I'd go for the model. The WCF template has a great example for this, refer to the `CompositeType` class in the `IService.cs`

Comment: So far i have learnt a lot. Some issues are still pending. Please tell me the format used in adding the connection string. How does the web service relate to the wp8 app and if I am to deploy it, where will i put the webservice. The application that i am designing will need to populate several text blocks. Does that mean that i will have to create a function for each operation that i need? I am addicted to being a two year old so please go on with that.

Comment: Please explain to me the format used when writing the connection strings. Where does my remote host address lie or how will communicate to the server. Talking about relationships, how are the two related? Do I need to upload anything to the server? Lastly clarify to me what a model is.. Still a two year old.