# Windows phone 8.1 app connect with a database

Tags: mysql, windows-phone-8.1, wamp

I'm totally new to the windows phone 8.1 app development.

I'm trying to develop a simple app with a database using visual studio 2013. It is not a silverlight app.

my app just have a text field and a button.And i have a MySQL database in a local server(WAMP).

I need to get a input from the text field and store it in the database.

First thing that I want to know is it possible to do?

If it is possible I would be very grateful if you could provide a step by step guide or a link where i can learn about this.

If it is not possible what are the other ways that I can try to store my input in a database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Local storage**

I'm guessing you're looking for a way to store structured data locally on the phone. AFAIK, MySQL is not supported on Windows Phone (MySQL is big, runs as a server, and it wouldn't be possible or practical to "install" it onto a phone). Instead what Microsoft endorses is to use SQLite. You'll first need to download the [SQLite library](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/5d97faf6-39e3-4048-a0bc-adde2af75d1b) as a Visual Studio extension. Then you'll need to install something like [SQLitePCL](https://sqlitepcl.codeplex.com/) (from [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SQLitePCL/3.8.2)) which essentially wraps the native SQLite library so that it is accessible from .NET languages. Make sure you add both references to your project. SQLite stores a database as a file that you can put in the local storage for your app.

**Remote storage**

I'm not sure if it's directly possible to connect to a remove MySQL server from a WP app. Usually you'd access a remote database through a webserver that exposes an API for you to use (e.g. a REST API). You can then send data to the webserver via a HTTP POST request, and then your webserver will store the data in the database. This is a big topic, and involves knowledge of server-side programming such as ASP.NET, Ruby on Rails, Django, PHP, etc. This topic is too broad for me to give you specifics on how to do this. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25399468/734040).

Comment: @ Decade Moon - thank you for your response. But  I hope to connect that app to a online server later. So Can I do that using SQLite?.

Comment: See my edit for remote storage. In this case, you typically wouldn't use SQLite.